# Facing error in recursive function for deriving factorial of a number

Tags: bash

I have written the following code to derive factorial of a given number. Being newbie to Shellscript, I used normal C code logic of recursive function.

```
#!/bin/bash
#This script will do factorial of a give number
echo "<<--------MENU----------->>"
echo "We will do a factorial"
echo "Enter the number"
 read num
 echo "You entred " $num
 fact()      #Function to calculate factorial of the given number
    {
        if  (num -eq 0)
            then    
        echo "1"
        elif (num -lt 0)
        then
        echo "Negative number can not be factorialed"
        else
        return fact*fact (n-1)
        fi
          }

        fact $num

        echo "The result is :" $fact(num)
```

I am getting following errors during execution:

```
<<--------MENU----------->>

We will do a factorial

Enter the number

4

You entred  4
fact.sh: 20: fact.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "fi")
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, `bash` is not "C". There are so many errors here that probably you need to read [a good tutorial on bash scripting](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html). You mix variable name and value, local and global variables, positional arguments, command evaluation, arithmetic expression, logical expressions...

First of all one advice: when you do not know what it's happening, use `#! /bin/bash -xv` as the first line. That will print each line before executing, and all the variable substitutions. Is really invaluable as debugging tool.

Next, I add a working version of the script. Mind you, this is a fast and dirty edit, there are plenty of bash expert here that will do a thousand time better script here.

```
#!/bin/bash
#This script will do factorial of a give number
fact()      #Function to calculate factorial of the given number
{
    local a
    if  [[ $1 -eq 0 ]]
    then    
        echo "1"
    elif [[ $1 -lt 0 ]]
    then
        echo "You can't take the factorial of a negative number"
    else
        a=$(fact $(($1 - 1)) )
        echo $(( $1 * $a ))
    fi
}
# main
echo "<<--------MENU----------->>"
echo "We will do a factorial"
echo "Enter the number"
read num
echo "You entred " $num

echo "The result is :" $(fact $num)
```

See:

```
[romano:~/tmp] % ./test.sh
<<--------MENU----------->>
We will do a factorial
Enter the number
4
You entred  4
The result is : 24
```

And now a little surprising one:

```
<<--------MENU----------->>
We will do a factorial
Enter the number
22
You entred  22
The result is : -1250660718674968576
```

...the analysis is left to the reader ;-)